# Getting the Initial and the end of consecutive dates Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, datetime

I want to write a code where it compares `dates` and `selected_dates` and states the intervals `selected_dates` occupies within `dates` and does not occupy. So it looks for consecutive number of times dates are in both `dates` and `selected_dates` have been in each other and records the timestamp of the start and end. The inverse as well so the consecutive number of times they have not been in each other seen in the `Non Occupying dates`. So we can see that the values `[2021-08-15 07:49:00', '2021-08-15 07:49:02', '2021-08-15 07:51:15', '2021-08-15 07:51:34']` are in both arrays so the initial and end would be shown as `2021-08-15 07:49:02 - 2021-08-15 07:51:34` in the `Occupying dates`. How would I be able to do such a thing and get the Expected Output?

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

dates = ['2021-08-15 03:16:34', '2021-08-15 03:17:24', '2021-08-15 03:20:02', '2021-08-15 05:56:17', '2021-08-15 05:57:01', '2021-08-15 07:49:00', '2021-08-15 07:49:02', '2021-08-15 07:51:15', '2021-08-15 07:51:34', '2021-08-15 08:33:39']
selected_dates= ['2021-08-15 03:16:34', '2021-08-15 03:17:24', '2021-08-15 07:49:02', '2021-08-15 07:51:15', '2021-08-15 07:51:34']
```

Expected Output

```
Occupying dates: 
2021-08-15 03:16:34 - 2021-08-15 03:17:24 ​
2021-08-15 07:49:02 - 2021-08-15 07:51:34
Non Occupying dates:
2021-08-15 03:20:02 - 2021-08-15 05:57:01
2021-08-15 08:33:39
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets for that (I've used some redundant code so you can see what's happening)

```
dates = ['2021-08-15 03:16:34', '2021-08-15 03:17:24', '2021-08-15 03:20:02', '2021-08-15 05:56:17', '2021-08-15 05:57:01', '2021-08-15 07:49:00', '2021-08-15 07:49:02', '2021-08-15 07:51:15', '2021-08-15 07:51:34', '2021-08-15 08:33:39']
selected_dates= ['2021-08-15 03:16:34', '2021-08-15 03:17:24', '2021-08-15 07:49:02', '2021-08-15 07:51:15', '2021-08-15 07:51:34']

found_in_both = set(dates).intersection(set(selected_dates))
found_only_once = set(dates).symmetric_difference(set(selected_dates))
```

Since the ordering is important for what you want, we can `sort` it out:

```
found_in_both = sorted(set(dates).intersection(set(selected_dates)))
found_only_once = sorted(set(dates).symmetric_difference(set(selected_dates)))
```

Now to just print your desired result format:

```
def print_date_list(date_list):
    for evens, odds in zip(date_list[::2], date_list[1::2]):
        print(evens, '-', odds)

    if len(date_list) % 2 == 1:
        print(date_list[-1])

print_date_list(found_in_both)
print_date_list(found_only_once)
```

Console output:

```
>>> print_date_list(found_in_both)
2021-08-15 03:16:34 - 2021-08-15 03:17:24
2021-08-15 07:49:02 - 2021-08-15 07:51:15
2021-08-15 07:51:34
>>> print_date_list(found_only_once)
2021-08-15 03:20:02 - 2021-08-15 05:56:17
2021-08-15 05:57:01 - 2021-08-15 07:49:00
2021-08-15 08:33:39
```